# Inlines with foriegnkey support

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In my app:

**models.py** (with just the relational fields)

```
class ContactList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Message(models.Model):
    list = models.ForeignKey(ContactList)

class Contact(models.Model):
    list = models.ForeignKey(ContactList)
```

Now from my Message admin I want to display inlines for the contacts of the selected ContactList. If I had said ContactList, I could write `ContactList.objects.all()[0].contact_set.all()` to get the contacts for that list (list `0` in that example). But how do I put this type of logic in my tabular inline?

**EDIT:**
Is this possible? Would I have to write my own forms to do this? Rearrange my model logic? I just wanna know what anyone else has done in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Since Message has a ForeignKey relatonship to Contact, why can't you just do this

```
class ContactListInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ContactList

Class MessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ContactListInline,
    ]
```

Comment: With that I get `<class 'canada.bulkmail.models.ContactList'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'canada.bulkmail.models.Message'>`. Its because what you mentioned is list saying put the contact _lists_ inline. And there is only one contact list, so it is not possible.